# WorkManager backoff delay doesn't work on some devices

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I want to start a `Worker` that performs some task, and in case of error tries again after some delay with exponential backoff strategy.

Here is simplified `Worker` for the sake of brevity:

```
class TestWorker(
    context: Context,
    workerParameters: WorkerParameters
) : Worker(
    context,
    workerParameters
) {
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Attempt $runAttemptCount")
        return Result.retry()
    }
}
```

And this is how I schedule this `Worker`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val TAG = "WORKER_TAG"
private val BACKOFF_DELAY_SECONDS = 60L

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance()
        workManager.cancelAllWork()
        val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(TestWorker::class.java)
            .setConstraints(
                Constraints
                    .Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                    .build()
            )
            .setBackoffCriteria(
                BackoffPolicy.EXPONENTIAL,
                BACKOFF_DELAY_SECONDS,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS
            )
            .addTag(TAG)
            .build()

        workManager.enqueue(workRequest)
    }
}
```

It works great on the majority of the devices, however I observe weird behaviour on some devices.

I expect Attempt 2 to be executed after 1 minute, but on Samsung J1, 6.0.1 I see the following log:

```
01-15 12:39:57.438 28396-28435/test.ru.workerissue D/DEBUG: Attempt 0
01-15 12:39:58.349 28396-28439/test.ru.workerissue D/DEBUG: Attempt 1
01-15 12:39:58.389 28396-28440/test.ru.workerissue D/DEBUG: Attempt 2
01-15 12:40:59.669 28396-28435/test.ru.workerissue D/DEBUG: Attempt 3
01-15 12:40:59.719 28396-28439/test.ru.workerissue D/DEBUG: Attempt 4
```

As you can see, the delay between all attempts except 2 and 3 is about 1 second.

If I run the same code on Nexus 6X, 8.1, I observe two attempts fired on startup simultaniously, and then everyting works as expected:

```
2019-01-15 13:01:06.610 28806-28841/test.ru.workerissue D/DEBUG: Attempt 0
2019-01-15 13:01:06.658 28806-28842/test.ru.workerissue D/DEBUG: Attempt 1
2019-01-15 13:02:06.747 28806-28975/test.ru.workerissue D/DEBUG: Attempt 2
2019-01-15 13:04:06.876 28806-29024/test.ru.workerissue D/DEBUG: Attempt 3
```

Also, I tested this on several other devices: Samsung Galaxy J3 - 8.0, Google Pixel XL - 8.1, Samsung Galaxy J1 - 5.1.1. Works as expected on all of these devices.

The version of `WorkManager` is `1.0.0-beta01`

What could be the reason of such inconsistency? Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the issue and it should be fixed in the next release of `WorkManager`: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122881597

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
[WorkManager 1.0.0-beta02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes#january_15_2019) has been released with [a fix for a bug that seems related to the problem you've](https://issuetracker.google.com/121998363)

> Fixed an edge case where periodic work could run more than once per interval on devices running Android 6.0 (API level 23).

**Original Answer:**
You should try to avoid to enqueue the WorkRequest every time that the application starts. WorkManager takes care of resuming the job for you and you don't need to do it.
For more information on WorkManager, and what it can do for you, you should take a look at [this blog series](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/introducing-workmanager-2083bcfc4712). There's also the video from Android Developer Summit talk ["Working with WorkManager"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83a4rYXsDs0) that explain this.

If you need to enqueue new works every time you app is started, I suggest that you enqueue it as an unique worker using the [`REPLACE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingWorkPolicy) policy:

```
private val TAG = "WORKER_TAG"
private val BACKOFF_DELAY_SECONDS = 60L

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance()
        val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(TestWorker::class.java)
            .setConstraints(
                Constraints
                    .Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                    .build()
            )
            .setBackoffCriteria(
                BackoffPolicy.EXPONENTIAL,
                BACKOFF_DELAY_SECONDS,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS
            )
            .addTag(TAG)
            .build()

        // The first parameter is a unique string that identifies the work, I'm using the TAG here.
        workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(TAG, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest)
    }
}
```

I see that you are using the `cancelAllWork()` methos. This is a dangerous method and you're not taking any action to stop your worker while it's running (like calling [`isStopped`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#isStopped())).

This may be the source of the additional log you get on the nexus device.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Actually in my real app I use the method you described and the issue still persists. I just simplified the project to the point where it still reproduces in order to localize the issue. But thanks nevertheless!